# PlayFramework, how to bind multiple values from other model in a form?

Tags: forms, playframework-2.1

I have two models like this :

```
MyModel
    public Long id;
    public String display;
    public List<OtherModel> others;

OtherModel
    public Long id;
    public String display;

    public static HashMap<String, String> listAsOptions() // Returns a list of <Id, Display> items for the select
```

In my form, I made a select like this :

```
@helper.select(form("others[]"), helper.options(models.OtherModel.listAsOptions), '_label -> "Others", 'id -> "form-others", '_showConstraints -> false, 'class -> "span3", 'multiple -> "multiple")
```

The problem is located at the name of this input, here, `others[]` : it doesn't work!

Normally, since we are relating to an other model, we should map it as `others[].id`, but id doesn't work either.

I tried these (without any luck):

- others.id
- others.id[]
- others[].id
- others
- others[]

The error depends on the name, but it never works.

How can I make it work ?